# How can I create an edge between a vertex and another edge?

Tags: vertices, edges

I want to be able to create an edge between a vertex and another edge, as shown in this picture.
[image: Problem Example]

I haven't had much luck with the knife tool since it seems to be a projection rather than a truly vertical cut based and the local Z axis of the vertex.

Comment: Try using Knife Tool in Ortho View -Numpad 5 key or View > View Persp/Ortho.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I did not realize that changing to orthographic view would change the way the knife cuts into the object. This solved my problem.

Comment: If I may give you my personal advice, always model in Ortho view ;)